# Error Struts 2 struts-default.xml

Tags: java, struts2, jboss

I'm trying to configure a project with struts2 + jboss 4.2.1.I have done many tests and trials I have read so much but I can not make it work.

I want to create a simple page index.I've tried changing various libraries to set the class-path libraries in Jboss but nothing. Always the same error:

```
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - Bean - jar:

WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar! / Struts-default.xml: 85:158
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration
```

Using the libraries

```
common-lang3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-chain-1.2.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-validator.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javassist.jar
ognl-2.6.11.jar
servlet-api-6.0.29.jar
struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar
xwork-2.1.3.jar
xwork-core-2.2.1.jar
```

In the web.xml file I added the tag with the configuration of struts2
I tried the exact same project with tomcat and works without problems.
I also tried to put the lib that are in the project in jboss but nothing has changed !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ViaProva</display-name>


 <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

As regards the  struts.xml this is the configuration. It all seems very linear versions of the jar I also changed several times as suggested in the net but it was not enough

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="addCustomerAction" 
            class="it.niuma.via.action.CustomerAction" method="addCustomer" >
            <result name="success">pages/customer.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="listCustomerAction" 
            class="it.niuma.via.action.CustomerAction" method="listCustomer" >
            <result name="success">pages/customer.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

Does anyone know give me some suggestion?

Comment: why your library version are different? make sure that struts2 jars should be of same version

Comment: Use Maven to manage dependency in the project instead of do it manually.

Comment: Include the entire stacktrace, too.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error message refer to a conflict between versions of the struts' jars.

I would recommend you to use Maven, instead of downloading the jars manually. Many issues around jars missing, conflicts, etc, will be solved by the Maven.